# Aggregate length of factor levels using two grouping columns in R

Tags: r, aggregate, grouping

I am trying to figure out how to aggregate one column that is a factor with a binary outcome (success/failure), using two grouping columns. One challenge is trying to also generate summary lines for group combinations that have a zero value for one outcome of the binary factor. For instance, say this is the following dataframe:

```
dat <- data.frame(
  Group1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"), 
  Group2 = c("D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "F", "F", "F"), 
  Result = c("Success", "Success", "Fail", "Success", "Success", "Success", "Fail", "Fail")
)
```

Ideally I would want a summary that looks like the following:

```
# Group1  Group2  Success Fail
# A       D       2       1
# B       E       2       0
# C       F       1       2
```

However I am struggling to generate a split column result.

I have attempted to use aggregate() with the following:

```
aggregate(Result ~ Group1 + Group2, data = dat, FUN=length)
```

But can't seem to split the binary factor variable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `dplyr::summarize()` and sum the values:

```
dat %>%
  summarise(Success = sum(Result == "Success"),
            Fail = sum(Result == "Fail"), 
            .by = c(Group1, Group2))
```

Output:

```
#  Group1 Group2 Success Fail
#1      A      D       2    1
#2      B      E       2    0
#3      C      F       1    2
```

Alternatively using base R and `aggregate`, though I am sure there has to be a more elegant way to do this, you can calculate the counts separately, `merge`, then use `setNames` to rename:

```
setNames(
  merge(
    aggregate(Result ~ Group1 + Group2, data = dat, FUN = \(x) sum(x == "Success")),
    aggregate(Result ~ Group1 + Group2, data = dat, FUN = \(x) sum(x == "Fail")),
    by = c("Group1", "Group2")),
  c("Group1", "Group2", "Success", "Fail")
  )

#  Group1 Group2 Success Fail
#1      A      D       2    1
#2      B      E       2    0
#3      C      F       1    2
```

Answer (score 2):

With `aggregate()`

```
dat$Result <- factor(dat$Result)
aggregate(Result ~ Group1 + Group2, data = dat, FUN = table)
#   Group1 Group2 Result.Fail Result.Success
# 1      A      D           1              2
# 2      B      E           0              2
# 3      C      F           2              1
```

With `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)
dcast(dat, Group1 + Group2 ~ Result)
# Key: <Group1, Group2>
#    Group1 Group2  Fail Success
#    <char> <char> <int>   <int>
# 1:      A      D     1       2
# 2:      B      E     0       2
# 3:      C      F     2       1
```

With `sqldf`

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("SELECT 
         Group1, Group2, 
         SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'Success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Success,
         SUM(CASE WHEN Result = 'Fail'    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fail 
       FROM dat 
       GROUP BY Group1, Group2")
#   Group1 Group2 Success Fail
# 1      A      D       2    1
# 2      B      E       2    0
# 3      C      F       1    2
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar way, using `pivot_wider()`:

```
dplyr::pivot_wider(dat, names_from = Result, values_from = Result, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
```

Notes:

1. `values_fn = length` finds the length of each combination of Group1, Group2, and Result in the dataset
2. For combinations without a row in the dataset, we fill with 0s using `values_fill`
3. Unsure what your actual dataset looks like, but if the outcomes are like in the example you gave, and there's only two possibilities (success and failure), then it makes sense to make them the logical values TRUE and FALSE or 1 and 0. If they're categories, making them factors is the way to go